# How to do reference to the floor in a building that's right below us?

Tags: word-request, terminology

I want to refer to the floor in a building that's right below us. I thought it is called "down stair", but not sure about it.

Do I need to provide more information to make my question clear?

Comment: *The floor below (us)*.

Comment: If I'm on the 5th floor of a building, and I want to reference the 4th floor, then, yes, I _can_ say "downstairs" (it's usually written in the plural plural and as one word). That said, I could also refer to the people working on the 2nd floor as "downstairs" as well. _Downstairs_ doesn't necessarily mean **exactly** one floor below where we are now.

Comment: @J.R. you can simply write that as an answer.

Comment: How about "one floor down"?

Comment: If I was on the fourth floor of an office building and I wanted to refer to the third floor, I would not use "downstairs" or "the floor below." I would say "the third floor."

Answer (score 1):

"Downstairs" can be used as a general placename for any floor lower than the one we're on - i.e. any place we could get to by going down some stairs.

There isn't a single-word term for "the floor below us (but not any of the floors below that one)".  I would just use "the floor below us".

Answer (score 1):

If I was on the fourth floor of an office building and I wanted to refer to the third floor, I would not use "downstairs" or "the floor below." I would say "the third floor."

That is the most natural and unambiguous way to refer to the floor that is right below us.

I would only use "downstairs" if there was one and one only floor below us. Or I would use "downstairs" to mean the lowest level of a building, or whatever is commonly referred to as "downstairs" in a particular building, be it the basement or street level or whatever.